# Display in html an element from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

I have created a function that generates an array in javascript. Once the array as been created i would like to display some of its items in html, however without using the  document.getElementById() in javascript.
Is there a way to select an item from the array directly in html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Distance calculator</title>

<script>
let myArray = [5, 7, 9]
var soluzioni =[]
    

function calcolo(){
    for(let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        var y = myArray[i];
        var risultato = y*y;
        soluzioni.push(risultato);
    document.getElementById('Calcolo').innerHTML =+ soluzioni[0] + "<br>";    
    }
     
}
    

</script>

    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="posizione">
        <button onclick="calcolo();"> calcola</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div id="Calcolo">
        
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Distance calculator</title>

<script>
let myArray = [5, 7, 9]
var soluzioni =[]
    

function calcolo(){
    for(let i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
        var y = myArray[i];
        var risultato = y*y;
        soluzioni.push(risultato);   
    }
     
}
    

</script>

    
</head>
<body>

    <div id="posizione">
        <button onclick="calcolo();"> calcola</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div id="Calcolo">
        <p> soluzioni[0] </p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to use a more advanced JavaScript framework, such as React or Angular or Vue.  You can get started on any introductory tutorials for those.  If you're looking to build something yourself, you'd need to build that functionality as the functionality you're suggesting is not natively available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agreed with @David. Plus, even if you could (horribly) writing the actual content of `soluzioni[0]` when you parse the `<p>` tag, it won't automatically update once you execute the function `calcolo`, and you will also end up with spaghetti code.

I would strongly suggest to use [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/), since it is "reactive" in exact that way; but framework such as the one mentioned by @David are a good solution.

Otherwise, in vanilla JS, the proper approach is using a reference to a node (using method such as `getElementById` or a `querySelector*` ones), and could looks like something as the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Distance calculator</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="posizione">
        <button> calcola</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div id="Calcolo">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <script>
      let myArray = [5, 7, 9];

      const calcolo = (arr) => arr.map(y => y * y);
      
      let button = document.querySelector("#posizione > button");
      let output = document.querySelector("#Calcolo > p");
      
      button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let soluzioni = calcolo(myArray);
        output.textContent = soluzioni[0];  
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```